# Custom Taxonomy Is Being Pulled into a Page, But It Doesn't Have A Hyperlink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a `WP_Query` class on the home page of a site that pulls in a custom post type, and as part of this I want to show the custom taxonomy (category) for this post type.

The solution I currently have pulls the taxonomy name in, but doesn't include the hyperlink? I would like it so when a user clicks this custom taxonomy it shows the related archive page for this taxonomy.

The specific snippet of code I'm using on the page in relation to the taxonomy is:

```
<p class="cat">
    <?php  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'news_categories' );
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo $term->name;
            }
    ?>
</p>
```

And the above snippet is part of this larger code block:

```
<?php 
    $homePageNews = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type'=> 'news'
    ));

    while(  $homePageNews->have_posts()){
            $homePageNews->the_post(); ?>

            <article class="article top-article lastest-news-article">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', 
                ['class' => 'image latest-top-image hover-class']); ?>
            </a>   
                <p class="cat">
                    <?php  $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'news_categories' );
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            echo $term->name;
                            }
                    ?> <a href=""></a>
                </p>
                <div class="content-wrapper content-wrapper-mobile-padding">
                    <h3 class="td no-bottom-margin hover-class"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="td top-latest-heading" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <hr>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></h3></p>
                </div>
            </article>

<?php } ?>

<?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Chewy you can try below code snippet.

```
<p class="cat">
    <?php
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'news_categories');
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_id    = $term->term_id;
        $term_name  = $term->name;
        $term_link  = get_term_link( $term_id );
        echo "<a href='".$term_link."'>".$term_name."</a>";
    }
    ?> 
</p>
```

please chcek and let me know if this work or not.

if not then please ping me I will definitely help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @DipPatel That worked. Thank you so much. Really appreciated !